# "../ path" works rather than "../../"

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was wondering how was that possible.

Technically, I have a *head.php* file that contains all of the stylesheets and javascripts:

*head.php*

```
<!--CLIENT-->

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

The file where the bootstrap.min.css is located is 2 folders up and I read somewhere that "../" is moving a step back. So I was wondering why it still works?

Here is the path information:

**C:\xampp\htdocs\renewSAD**

-includes folders client,css,fonts, & js.

inside the css folder are all the bootstrap css files.

`in the client folder
**C:\xampp\htdocs\renewSAD\client**

it includes another folder which is the **head.php**
Therefore it is 2 folders away for the css folder. How come a single **../** works in locating the path for bootstrap's css?

I asked this question because I think it might cause an error in the future.

Comment: That might have something to do with "how" you're probably including/requiring files. If one of those PHP files contains one that is getting files one level down, then that could be it. It's next to impossible to answer though, without seeing what your actual php file(s) look like.

Comment: Hi again @Fred-ii- I tried deleting it all and start over again. And found out the same thing as you've said. There is a *clientRegistration.php* file in my client folder, so technically inside the **client folder** are *includes folder* & *clientRegistration.php*. The clientRegistration.php includes the head.php file inside the **includes* folder. So `<?php include 'includes/head.php';?> ` It turns out when I include a file that  is another folder away, it will inherit the path of the file that includes it. I hope you understand what I've said. Explaining and English is not my forte :)

Comment: You've explained quite well ;-) It sounds like an inheritance to me. A good way I find to include files instead of relative paths, is to go straight to the root `/var/usr/public/(folders/sub-folders)/file(s)` using a full system path, when in doubt. There are few ways to do this using the $_SERVER superglobal and other functions.

Comment: Glad I'd explained it well :D. Thanks for the advice Fred :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you have the following structure:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\renewSAD
  - Client
    - Another folder
      - head.php
  - CSS
    - bootstrap.min.css
    - ...
  - Fonts
  - JS
```

Any chance that your `index.php` is actually located in the Client folder, and `head.php` just gets included in that file?

If so, this works because paths are relative to the main script (not the included script). You can use `getcwd()` to verify the current directory.

Comment: Exactly :D. I forgot to mention the inside that `client folder` are the file that includes the `head.php` and the another folder(which contains the `head.php`).